# Computing combinations of variables

Tags: combinations, stata, combinatorics

I am computing combinations of variables in Stata and I have four poverty variables below:

```
improved_toilet 0 "No" 1"Yes" // 1 means household lacks toilet,0 means no lack      
improved_water 0 "No" 1"Yes" // 1 means household lacks water,0 means no lack  
durable_house 0 "No" 1"Yes" // 1 means household lacks durable house, 0 means no lack  
living_spce 0 "No" 1"Yes" // 1 means household lacks living space, 0 means no lack
```

The issue is, with my code below, if I had say 15 variables with say 10 categories each it would be almost impossible to manually compute the combinations.

I would like to know if there is a way to make this work easier and less manual, with more efficient coding.

```
    ** Hence
    gen poverty= (1-improved_toilet) + (1-improved_water) + (1-durable_house) + (1-living_spce)
    
    
    ****************
    * SIngle Deprivations. => poverty == 1
    ***************
    **  
     
    * Single  combinations: there are 4C1 = 4!/1!3! = 4
                                       
    *lack improved_toilet improved_water - A
    gen lack_toilet_only = 0
    replace lack_toilet_only = 1 if improved_toilet == 1 & poverty == 1
    
    *lack improved_water only  - B
    gen lack_water_only = 0
    replace lack_water_only = 1 if improved_water == 1 & poverty == 1
    
    *lack durable_house  only  - C
    gen lack_house_only = 0
    replace lack_house_only = 1 if durable_house == 1 & poverty == 1
    
    *lack Living space  only  - D
    gen lack_living_only = 0
    replace lack_living_only = 1 if living_spce == 1 & poverty == 1
    
    *******************************************************************************
    ** Pairwise deprivations: => poverty == 2
    *******************************************************************************
    
     /* Pairwise combinations: there are 4C2 = 4!/2!2! = 6 pairs that can be generated
    *** our list improved_toilet improved_water durable_house living_spce if pair_poor==1
    -                  A            B                  C         D
    -The combos are: AB, AC, AD, BC , BD, CD.                                     */
    
                                        
    *lack improved_toilet improved_water - AB
    gen lack_toilet_water = 0
    replace lack_toilet_water  = 1 if improved_toilet==1 & improved_water ==1 &  poverty == 2 
    
    *lack improved_toilet & durable_house - AC
    gen lack_toilet_house =0
    replace lack_toilet_house = 1 if improved_toilet==1 & durable_house ==1 &  poverty == 2 
    
    *lack improved_toilet and living_spce - AD
    gen lack_toilet_living_spce =0
    replace lack_toilet_living_spce = 1 if improved_toilet==1 & living_spce ==1 &  poverty == 2 
    
    *lack improved water and durable house - BC
    gen lack_water_house =0
    replace lack_water_house = 1 if improved_water ==1 & durable_house==1 &  poverty == 2 
    
    *lack improved water and and living_spce - BD
    gen lack_water_living_spce =0
    replace lack_water_living_spce = 1 if improved_water ==1 & living_spce==1 &  poverty == 2 
    
    *lack durable house and living_spce - CD
    gen lack_house_living_spce =0
    replace lack_house_living_spce = 1 if durable_house==1 & living_spce==1 &  poverty == 2 
    
    ************************************************************************************
     ** Triple deprivations poverty: Having 3 deprivations  =>poverty == 3
     **********************************************************************************
     
     /* Poverty by 3 deprivations: since the order doesnt matter, This is combination,
    n is the total number of items and r is the number of items to be chosen, hence 4C3
    => there are = n!/(r!(n-r)!) = 4!/(3!(4-3)!) = = 24/(6*1) = 4 combinations. 
    *** our list improved_toilet improved_water durable_house living_spce if tri_poor==1
    -                  A            B                  C         D
    -The combos are: ABC,ABD,BCD,CDA.                                             */ 
                                         
    
    *lack improved_toilet improved_water and durable_house - ABC
    gen lack_toilet_water_house = 0
    replace lack_toilet_water_house  = 1 if improved_toilet==1 & improved_water ==1& durable_house ==1 & poverty == 3
    
    **lack improved_toilet improved_water and living_spce - ABD
    gen lack_toilet_water_living_spce = 0
    replace lack_toilet_water_living_spce  = 1 if improved_toilet==1 & improved_water ==1 & living_spce ==1 & poverty == 3
    
    **lack improved_water,durable_house and  living_spce - BCD
    gen lack_water_house_living_spce = 0
    replace lack_water_house_living_spce = 1 if improved_water ==1 & durable_house ==1 & living_spce ==1 & poverty == 3
    
    **lack durable_house,  living_spce and improved_toilet   - CDA
    gen lack_house_living_spce_toilet = 0
    replace lack_house_living_spce_toilet = 1 if durable_house ==1 & living_spce ==1 & improved_toilet==1  & poverty == 3
    
    
    ***********************************************************************************
    ** All 4 deprivatisons poverty:   =>poverty == 4
    ********************************************************************************
    ** Combinations Here are 4C4 = 4!/(4!1!) =1 
    
     gen lacks_toilet_water_house_living_spce = 0
     replace lacks_toilet_water_house_living_spce   = 1 if poverty == 4 
     lab var lacks_toilet_water_house_living_spce  "Household lacks all four deprivations"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the smallest level you can save on code by noting that (e.g.)

```
gen lack_toilet_water_house = 0
replace lack_toilet_water_house  = 1 if improved_toilet==1 & improved_water ==1& durable_house ==1 & poverty == 3
```

can be reduced to

```
gen lack_toilet_water_house = improved_toilet==1 & improved_water==1 & durable_house==1 & poverty==3
```

Otherwise see `tuples` from SSC.

```
ssc describe tuples 
ssc install tuples
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the orientation. Let me look at tuples. Very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to save time is to encode your categorical variables into numeric values. Then create a loop over your combinations. Here is an example:

```
 local values 2 4 5 8 11
 foreach i of local values {
     foreach j of local values {
         if `j'>`i' gen newvar_`i'_`j' = `i' + `j' if inlist(poverty_variable_name,`i',`j')

 } 
 }
```

Then you can modify the loop for higher order combinations as needed.

Good luck!

Comment: I can't follow this.  In your example this creates 10 new variables from a variable with 5 possible values, so that for example observations with values either 2 or 5 both get coded 7; otherwise missing. The OP's problem is not about single variables, but about combinations of variables, 2 at a time, and so on.

Comment: You haven't responded to comment (time zones might be a factor) but I still can't see this as an answer or even that the variables produced would be of any use for any other purpose. Note further in your example that 2 and 11 and 5 and 8 have the same sum, although it would be attained in different pairs of values.

Comment: Great point. The example is meant to show the utility of the loop structure.  The problems that you, Nick, identify are easily resolved by converting the numeric values to strings, then changing the internal function to concatenate successive pairs of strings.  Basically, encode the factors first for ease of use, then -- using concatenate, rather than numeric addition -- use the loop to create the necessary combinations.  Sample code inside the loop could be:  gen stringPair = str1 + str2

Comment: You're saying that the code could be brought closer to the question, which would naturally be a good step.

Comment: A good step that pointed me in the right direction on the possibilities. Thanks all.